# Error al iniciar programa con node.js

Tags: nodejs

Quería iniciar una aplicación en node.js y me sale el siguiente error:

```
Error: The module '\\?\C:\Users\Usuario\node_modules\better-sqlite3\build\Release\better_sqlite3.node'
was compiled against a different Node.js version using
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 83. This version of Node.js requires
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 93. Please try re-compiling or re-installing
the module (for instance, using `npm rebuild` or `npm install`).
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1183:18)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at bindings (C:\Users\Usuario\node_modules\bindings\bindings.js:112:48)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Usuario\node_modules\better-sqlite3\lib\database.js:9:24)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32) {
  code: 'ERR_DLOPEN_FAILED'
}
```

Versión de npm->8.3.0 y versión de node->16.13.1

Alguien me puede ayudar?

Comment: _Please try re-compiling or re-installing the module (for instance, using `npm rebuild` or `npm install`)._ ¿Intentaste lo que dice el mensaje?

Comment: Sí, puse eso en la consola pero nada

Comment: Agrega a tu pregunta la versión de nodejs (`node -v`) y npm (`npm -v`)

Comment: Intenta eliminar la carpeta `node_modules` y haz de nuevo `npm install`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error que te ha lanzado significa que la última versión de la librería que has instalado *better_sqlite3* no es compatible con tu versión actual de node, para ello tienes 2 opciones:

1. Actualizar tu versión de NodeJS:

---

Actualiza en el sistema a la última estable,
o como mínimo, que cumpla con el requisito de *NODE_MODULE_VERSION
93*, para ello te dejo [aquí un
enlace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8191459/how-do-i-update-node-js)
de stackoverflow para hacerlo.

2. Instalar una versión inferior de *better_sqlite3*

---

No sé si estabas utilizando better_sqlite3 anteriormente, si la librería ha comenzado a fallar
actualmente, es muy probable que hayas hecho un **npm update** de
las dependencias y ahora te tire el error de incompatibilidad. Si ha
sido este el caso puedes hacer lo siguiente:

> **rimraf ./url_carpeta_node_modules**
> *Nota: Si no tienes rimraf como comando, te recomiendo que lo instales, elimina la carpeta node_modules en un instante, si la eliminas manualmente tardará un rato, [ejemplo instalación windows](https://www.cheezycode.com/2016/07/how-to-delete-nodemodules-folder-npm.html).*
>
> Acto seguido, modifica en el package.json manualmente la versión de la librería a una que sea compatible con tú versión de NodeJS.
>
> Una vez hecho esto, ejecuta un **npm install** y todo debería de funcionar correctamente.

Comment: Gracias por tu aporte Javier. Lo que pasaba era, como bien dices, que la librería de sqlite no era compatible con la versión de node, ya que había actualizado node pero no sqlite. Así que lo he arreglado instalando la última versión de sqlite.